# Bodyparser breaking fresh installation of adonis 4.1

Tags: body-parser, adonis.js

> mygame@4.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js

Error: Cannot find module '@adonisjs/bodyparser/providers/BodyParserProvider'
Require stack:

- /usr/src/app/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/require-stack/index.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/index.js
- /usr/src/app/server.js

1 requireStack
/usr/src/app/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js:44

2 anonymous
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Registrar/index.js:104

3 arrayMap
/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:653

4 Function.map
/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9622

5 interceptor
/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:17094

6 thru
/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:8859

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mygame@4.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mygame@4.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-03-25T00_06_01_885Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem is npm is installing the wrong version from body-parser, due to a recent push.

As a workaround:

1. go to package.json
2. you can replace the ^ with ~

   "@adonisjs/bodyparser": "~2.0.9",

Since we prefixed the version with ~, NPM retrieved the latest patch version under the 2.0.9 minor version, which turned out to be 2.0.9 itself

For more info: https://github.com/adonisjs/bodyparser/issues/43